# php warning session variable, Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, session

```
if($_SESSION["adm"]==NULL)
   header("location:signin.php");
```

By this code, I want to check the session variable for it is empty or not. While loading the home page first time, the session variable will be usually null.  If the session variable is null the page should redirect to `Login` page, else it will stay in the `Home` page itself.

Error ->>> 
Notice: Undefined index: adm in....

Comment: Show your code please?

Comment: if($_SESSION["adm"]==NULL) header("location:signin.php");

Comment: @nisfan..No one can figure out the issue if you won't post full code.

Comment: Boss its about 154 lines. :( How can I ? Its for a `sign in` page. If the session is set goto to user home page else need a sign-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After assign any value, this warning never shows.

Only try and use the `SESSION` once it's set, or do something like;

```
if( array_key_exists('adm', $_SESSION) ) {
  //It exists
} else {
  //It doesn't exist
}
```

Or use the ternary operator and set a default - kind of a "hacky" way, though.

```
$_SESSION['adm'] = array_key_exists('adm', $_SESSION) ? $_SESSION['adm'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that you have included `session_start()` in the beginning of the PHP page.

2) Always try to access `SESSION` variable only if it is set with a value.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['adm']))
{
   // perform the operations
}
```

Comment: I need a solution for the 2nd option. I use session in an `sign-in` page. And i like to  check the session on other pages, to check it is set or not. if I directly goto any other page except sign-in, the warning shows. o.O